# Android Supporting Different Languages

Tags: android, localization

Is there a way to trick my device into thinking I am in a different location in order to test Supporting Different Languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and change the language settings.
On the other hand, I found an interesting [article](http://www.androidsocialmedia.com/apps/fool-change-your-gps-location-on-android) talking about an app that changes your actual GPS coordinates.